# PHP Regex for Greek mobile phone with prefix 69

Tags: php, validation, phone-number

I would wish a PHP regex in order to validate Greek mobile phone numbers.
The number must contains 10 digits.
The first two numbers must be 69xxxxxxxx

Comment: Voted down because there is no indication of any research to find answer for extremely simple problem.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**GREEK Mobile Number Validation**

You can `preg_match()` to validate **10-digit** mobile numbers **`^69`** first two number should be start with 69:

```
//Example
$mobile_number = 6955555559;// Your number

//Checking phone number
if(preg_match('/^69[0-9]{8}+$/', $mobile_number)){
    echo "Correct number";
}else{
    echo "Wrong number";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Maths RkBala. Your solution is very helpful!

Comment: @Αρης Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

**//Following script is PHP Regex for Greek mobile phone with prefix 69 and to validate 10-digit numbers. This ^[6]{1}[9]{1} will check for particular 69 in front and this [0-9]{8}$ will check 8 numbers**

```
$phone = "6988888888";
$validation = "/^[6]{1}[9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/";
preg_match($validation,$phone,$m);

echo $m[0];

// Output: 6988888888
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.